# Can't find some apps installed from Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, software-center, gnome-software

First Ubuntu Software app renamed as only "Software" (and also orange logo has gone) and then when I search in all apps list in Ubuntu, I can't find apps that I installed from Ubuntu Software.

I can only find them if I search on Software app, they are installed, and I can only launch from there by clicking launch button.